# Login page and profile page redirection the system do not display the right page

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a login page that allow user to submit a registered email and password and if the data is correct then the system redirect to the profile page and here i face the problem .

when I try to submit the write data the system do not redirect me to the profile page .

but if I echo a confirm message that the data are correct the browser display this message

how to fixx this problem ???

## login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once('include/connect.php');
$message = ""; 
if(!empty($_POST['email']))
{

$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

$email = strip_tags($email);
$pass = strip_tags($pass);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($pass);
//$pass = md5($pass);

$sql=mysql_query( "SELECT user_id, email_address, first_name FROM user WHERE email_address='$email'AND password='$pass'LIMIT 1") or die("error in user table");
$login_check = mysql_num_rows($sql);

  if($login_check > 0)
  {
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

          $id = $row['user_id'];
          $_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;

          $firstname = $row['first_name'];
          $_SESSION['first_name']= $firstname;

          $email = $row['email_address'];
          $_SESSION['email_address']= $email;

          mysql_query("UPDATE user SET last_log_date=now() WHERE user_id='$id'");

        //$message = "correct email and passworddd!!";  
          header("Location: profile.php");    
  }//close if 
  else
  {
      $message = "incorrect Email or Password!!";
      //exit();
  }
}//close if

?>
```

## profile.php

```
<?php
session_start();
 require_once('include/connect.php'); 


if(isset($_GET['user_id']))
{
    $id=$_GET['user_id'];
    var_dump($id);

}
elseif(isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
    $id= $_SESSION['user_id'];
}

else
{
    print "Important  data  are missing";
    print_r($_SESSION);
    exit();

}

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user  WHERE user_id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

   $firstname=$row['first_name'];
   $lastname=$row['last_name'];
   $birth_date=$row['birth_date'];
   $registered_date=$row['registered_date'];
   //***************for upload img*****************//
   $check_pic="members/$id/image01.jpg";
   $default_pic="members/0/image01.jpg";
   if(file_exists($check_pic))
   {
       $user_pic="<img src=\"$check_pic\"width=\"100px\"/>";
   }
   else
   {
       $user_pic="<img src=\"$default_pic\">";
   }
   echo $id, $firstname, $birth_date;
?>
```

Comment: so the only thing not working is `header("Location: profile.php");` ?

Comment: yes it i think so do you know how to fix this problem?????

Answer (score 0):

Easy :) Just put all this code on the top of content and be sure that there is no any content on the page where `header("Location: profile.php");` is working, because if there is something it can't be loaded. I also recommend to use `exit;` after `header("Location: profile.php");`